# How to split one dataframe column into many columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

- I am learning pandas
- I have one dataframe column which has multiple values in a string separated by space
- I have to split this column into many columns
- Problem is - the split may give variable number of values
- My code is as under:

  ```
  import pandas as pd 



  df = pd.DataFrame({'institute': ['Learn Free Academy', 
                                   'Free Code Academy',
                                   'Avon IT School'],
                      'languages': ['Java,JavaScript:Python;HTML\CSS',
                                    'HTML/CSS\JavaScript',
                                    'C:C#']})

  # print(df )
  #             institute                        languages
  # 0  Learn Free Academy  Java,JavaScript:Python;HTML\CSS
  # 1   Free Code Academy              HTML/CSS\JavaScript
  # 2      Avon IT School                             C:C#
  ```

When I split 'languages' column, I get following result:

```
  print( df['languages'].str.get_dummies(r';|:|\\|\/|,') )

  #    C  C#  CSS  HTML  Java  JavaScript  Python  |
  # 0  0   0    0     0     0           0       0  0
  # 1  0   0    0     0     0           0       0  0
  # 2  0   0    0     0     0           0       0  0
```

How do I get following result?

```
  #    Java  Javascript      Python  HTML   CSS  C  C#
  # 0     1           1           1     1     1  0   0
  # 1     0           1           0     1     1  0   0 
  # 2     0           0           0     0     0  1   1
```

Comment: Use `df['languages'].str.get_dummies(' ')`

Comment: You are right your suggestion works, but, where string separator is ' '.  However, when I have multiple delimiters like comma, semi-colon, colon, slash, forward slash etc., I do not get the required result.  Can you throw light on whether I am passing the argument to the function is correct or not.  

Comment: Answer was added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) for `|` because default separator in [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
print (df['languages'].str.replace(r';|:|\\|\/|,','|'))
0    Java|JavaScript|Python|HTML|CSS
1                HTML|CSS|JavaScript
2                               C|C#
Name: languages, dtype: object

df1 = df['languages'].str.replace(r';|:|\\|\/|,','|').str.get_dummies()
print(df1)
   C  C#  CSS  HTML  Java  JavaScript  Python
0  0   0    1     1     1           1       1
1  0   0    1     1     0           1       0
2  1   1    0     0     0           0       0
```